# Mocha async load a set of test case data and then dynamically create test cases

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mocha.js

My issue: I'd like to load an array of test case *data* (not test cases themselves), and then run that set of test cases. All actions, loading the data and the methods being tested, are async.

```js
//testData.js
module.exports.loadTestData() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var testDataArr = [];

        //do some async stuff and populate `testDataArr`
        setTimeout(1000, function(){
            testDataArr.push({
                "message": "test description 1",
                "data": "abcd" //data to pass to func
            })

            testDataArr.push({
                "message": "test description 1",
                "data": "abcd" //data to pass to func
            })

            resolve(testDataArr);
        })
    })
}

//myTests.test.js
const MyModule       = require('../index.js');
const TestDataHelper = require('./testData');
const chai           = require('chai');
const chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

const expect = chai.expect;

describe('#myTests', function(){
    describe('#aFunction', function(){
        describe('should fail', function(){
            var failureCases;

            before(async function(){
                 failureCases = await TestDataHelper.getTestData();
            })

            it('load test data', function(done){
                //dummy test to cause the "before" to run and load test data
            })

            failureCases.forEach(function(case){
                it(case.message, async function(){
                    await expect(MyModule.aFunction(case.data)).to.eventually.be.rejected;
                })
            })
        })
    })
})
```

The above was my latest attempt to get this to work (i.e. using the dummy function to get the async test data to load before the `forEach`), but I still get the following error:

```sh
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
```

It may be obvious, but I've got a chicken or egg problem and I'm not sure how to solve it. Because `describe` [doesn't support returned promises](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/2975), I haven't found a way to asynchronously load the test data into an array, and then loop over that array to dynamically generate test cases.

Some other workarounds I've tried (including using the `--delay` flag):

//Attempted Workaround #1 (using the --delay flag)

```js
var failureCases;

TestDataHelper.getTestData().then(function(arr){
    failureCases = arr;

    run();
})

describe('#myTests', function(){
    describe('#aFunction', function(){
        describe('should fail', function(){
            failureCases.forEach(function(case){
                it(case.message, async function(){
                    await expect(MyModule.aFunction(case.data)).to.eventually.be.rejected;
                })
            })
        })
    })
})

//mocha --delay still produces "Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined" error
```

Attempted Workaround #2 (loading data in an async test case and then dynamically creating more)

```js
describe('#myTests', function(){
    describe('#aFunction', function(){
        describe('should fail', function(){
            it('load test data', async function(done){
                var failureCases = await TestDataHelper.getTestData();

                failureCases.forEach(function(case){
                    it(case.message, async function(){
                        await expect(MyModule.aFunction(case.data)).to.eventually.be.rejected;
                    })
                })
            })
        })
    })
})
```

In this workaround, mocha doesn't produce an error, but it doesn't appear to actually run the dynamically-generated tests because I only get the following output:

```sh
> mocha

#myTests
  #aFunction
    should fail
      load test data ✓
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Using `--delay/run()` will work, if used correctly. The `describes actually need to be executed in the same block AFTER the async method completes.

Going back to my "Attempted Workaround #1", it should look like this:

```js
> mocha --delay

//myTests.test.js
TestDataHelper.getTestData().then(function(failureCases){

    describe('#myTests', function(){
        describe('#aFunction', function(){
            describe('should fail', function(){
                failureCases.forEach(function(case){
                    it(case.message, async function(){
                        await expect(MyModule.aFunction(case.data)).to.eventually.be.rejected;
                    })
                })
            })
        })
    })

    run();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a somewhat old question but having to use an option like `--delay` did not seem to sit right with me and I was having the same issue in one of my tests.  I got mine working by simply wrapping the test case in its own closure.  I think the following would work for your case.

```
describe('#myTests', function(){
    describe('#aFunction', function(){
        describe('should fail', function(){
            function itArray(case) {
                it(case.message, async function(){
                    await expect(MyModule.aFunction(case.data)).to.eventually.be.rejected;
                })
            }
            failureCases.forEach(function(case){
               itArray(case);
            })
        })
    })
})
```